# Counting time in python?

Tags: python, datetime, counting

Without manipulating the actual date and time using the `datetime` module, is there any way to basically say:

```
# wait x amount of time

call_function()
```

Is there any way to replicate that without using `datetime`? If not, how would I do it using `datetime`?

Comment: `import time time.sleep(seconds)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
time.sleep(5) #wait 5 seconds
```